# Compress full directory with bzip2 into a tar file whose name depends on the current date

Tags: bash, compression, syntax-error, bzip2

I'm trying to compress a directory but I want to change the `tar` file name to have the current date.  The problem is that `tar` doesn't accept:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -cvjSf $(date +%d/%m/%y.%HH:%MM)home_backup.tar.bz2 /home
```

I want to make a compressed File with bzip2 with the actual date but the name is not accepted. It only works if I use a simple name like:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -cvjSf home.tar.bz2 /home
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't put `:` or `/` in the name of the tar file.

Try:

```
tar -cvjSf "$(date +%d-%m-%y.%HH.%MM)home_backup.tar.bz2" /home
```

Notes:

1. In Unix, `/` means directory.  The expansion of `$(date +%d/%m/%y.%HH:%MM)home_backup.tar.bz2` will contain two `/` and tar would want to create the file in specified subdirectory.  In the command above, we replaced `/` with `-` and the problem is avoided.
2. `tar` treats the part of a file name that precedes `:` as the name of a remote host.  Since you are not trying to send the file to a remote host, all `:` should be removed from the `date` command that is used to create the file name.  In the command above, we replaced `:` with `.` and the problem is avoided.
3. The command above shows the name of the tar file inside double-quotes.  With the specific command shown above, this is not necessary.  The use of double-quotes, however, prevents word-splitting and this may save you from unpleasant surprises in the future.